# How do can I share a PDF and interact with it remotely?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jakarta-ee, pdf

I want to make an functionality in which user can share the url of uploaded PDF. Now when the another user open the same pdf with given url, first person will scroll down and on another user can see the scrolled content directly or the pdf will be automatically scrolled.

Is it possible using Java, JavaScript or another technology?

> Ex. Person 1 has shared exaple.pdf with person 2 by giving link of it.
>
> Person 2 had clicked on link and the pdf is opened at his side.
>
> Now person 1 is scrolling the pdf to page no. 3 and at the same time on the Person 2's screen the pdf will be auto scrolled to page no. 3.

Please let me know if my issue is still not clear.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I wouldn't definitely use `PDF` format because it's really hard to manipulate with. Instead of that, you could make your a document a `HTML` file and then listen to page events with JQuery (like [scroll event](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_scroll.asp)). So far so good, this is the easy part.

Now you need to make clients communicate with each other so I think [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is the best way for it. If you insist on Java, you can use brand new [WebSocket API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/websocket.htm) but it can be also implemented in pure JavaScript like [Socket IO](http://socket.io/) so you don't even have to use Java for it.

But if you have to work with PDFs, then good luck, it's going to be really tough task.

Answer (score 0):

As Petr Mensik said it would be probably pretty hard to do it with PDF file with Java, JavaScript.

But if you really want I guess it would be appropriate to check some Adobe SDK. I'm not sure but maybe Adobe AIR or Flex or other Flash application.